# Join different query Results in a Stored Procedure into one dataset

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a Table

```
GO
CREATE TABLE Commentary.Basic_Information (
    ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    CompanyID varchar(100),
    Count_1 int, 
    Quote_1 decimal(10,2),
    timestamp date, 
    shipment int
```

that gets filled by a stored procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [Commentary].[Add_Basic_Information]
(
    @companyID varchar(max) = NULL,
    @year varchar(max) = NULL
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    insert into Basic_Information(Company, Count_1, Quote_1, [timestamp])
    select 
        @companyID as Untgscod, @year as SurveyYear,  COUNT(case when oq.x <> '' and [case] = @year and untgscod = @companyid  then 1 end) as Count, 
        CAST(COUNT(case when oq.x <> '' and [case] = @year and untgscod = @companyid  then 1 end)  as decimal(10,2))
        /CAST(COUNT(case when [case] = @year then 1 end)  as decimal(10,2)) as Quote,
        GETDATE() as [TimeStamp]
    from Q_Questions
```

this is just a shortcut. Important is actually, that I have a stored procedure and that I want to add another value from another query into the shipment field.

```
insert into basic_information(MA1, MA2)
    select 
        coalesce(Shipments__c + ShipmentsNotValid__c, Shipments__c, shipmentsnotvalid__c), 
    from Project
```

What I did is I just copied the latter code under the first. But this did not work since it is not copied behind the first dataset.

The result dataset should look like

ID   | CompanyID | Count_1 | Quote_1 | timestamp | shipment
1    | 232       | 23432   | 0.345   | ...       | 43

How do I get the result of the second query into the table in one stored procedure?

Comment: *"How do I get the result of the second query"* Your second query (well both actually) is an `INSERT` statement; there is no result set returned.

Comment: Can you eloborate on the link between "ID | CompanyID | Count_1 | Quote_1 | timestamp | shipment 1" and "232 | 23432 | 0.345 | ... | 43"? I think that what you want is to have column names and values on one line. If this is the case, there needs to be a link. Or you need to rely on a cursor, which I do not see in the examples.